# Kubuntu: debugging C++ application in GDB mutes the application's audio

Tags: c++, ubuntu, audio, gdb

I'm trying to debug an application on my newly-installed Kubuntu system. When I launch the application outside of the debugger, sounds generated by the application are audible as normal. However, when I launch it via the debugger, no sounds are audible and the application does not show up in Kubuntu's jumplist of applications that are currently providing audio.

I've not come across an issue like this before, and I'm not sure whether it's an issue with my system or with the GDB setup. Does anyone know how I could go about diagnosing the issue here?

My system:

- Kubuntu 20.04 64-bit, kernel 5.4.0-42-generic
- KDE Plasma: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks: 5.68.0
- GDB: (Ubuntu 9.1-0ubuntu1) 9.1
- IDE: VS Codium 1.48.0 (as a snap), using the Native Debug extension

My debugger launch configuration:

```
{
    "name": "Launch Afterburner",
    "type": "gdb",
    "request": "launch",
    "target": "${workspaceFolder}/build/debug/bond",
    "arguments": "-dev 5 -toconsole -windowed -width 1920 -height 1080",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/debug",
    "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
    "env":
    {
        "LD_LIBRARY_PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/build/debug"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the application binary have set-uid or set-gid permissions? It would not have them when running under GDB, and you may have to run GDB as root.

Comment: It has neither, as far as I can see.